# When are the Apptivate 2013 winners going to be made public?

Tags: support, apptivate.ms

When are the results of the [apptivate contest](http://apptivate.ms/) expected to be published? It is already the 16th of June. On the site it is written that the result is going to be announced on the 15th of June. But no information seems to be available. Please let me know the winners.

> [image]

Comment: Let me guess; This Skeet fellow participated, won each and every price, and now they are embarrassed to announce this publicly...

Comment: @Bart I fear more the generic "6 to 8 weeks".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Either that or "caching". Don't know how that would apply, but then again, the answer is always "caching"

Comment: @Bart yeah, wish World Peace would also be cached!

Comment: Keep your eye on [this page](http://apptivate.ms/contest).  Said to be updated with the winners on June 15th.  That was yesterday, a Saturday in Redmond.  Give them a few more days, I'd say.

Comment: @Oded♦ The judges have spoken! Congratulations to the winners, and thanks to all for participating!
what this sentence saying? How they can congratulating winner without announcing them? and Judges have spoken means?

Comment: @Vandana The judges spoke "Its weekend dude! Don't bother me"

Comment: They did say June 15th, but never said which year. 2113 is my guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops. The site flipped itself to "Here are the winners!!1" mode before it was told who the winners were. This will be remedied **tomorrow, June 17th**, during the business day of Eastern U.S. time. My apologies for the delay.

Comment: Update on the main apptivate site regarding this.... And how result declared its on site or by mail, and what is the process to get prize of contest ???

Comment: The winners will be announced on the main http://apptivate.ms homepage. Winners will be contacted privately for information relating to prizes.

Comment: "site flipped itself to..." - funny!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Apptivate 2: Rise of the Machines

Comment: @Abby I'm sure there's a flesh and blood dev to blame behind this mischief. :D